# What makes singular regular points "special", and allows them to have series solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Most textbooks on differential equations simply define ordinary, singular regular and irregular points and state that the first two have series solutions for particular differential equations. But why? Why is it that a singular regular point, $x_0$, for the equation $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)=0$ has a solution if $(x-x_0)P(x)$ is analytic at $x_0$ (equivalently with a squared term for $Q(x)$)?

Comment: Just checking: Have you tried expanding $y$ as a power series in $x - x_0$ with unknown coefficients, substituting into the ODE, and expressing the coefficients recursively?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Well I did it, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for in relation to this.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that's how the classification arises: to distinguish when Frobenius method work or not. Wikipedia has a good enough explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point